# 'Takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given' in python

Tags: python-3.x

If i have a class in network_final.py:

```
    class Network_1:

        def network_combine1A_1(self, input_shape1, input_shape2):
            input1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape1)
            input2 = keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape2)

            ...
```

...on which I call network_combine1A_1() like so...

```
from network_final import Network_1

input_shape1 = (128, 130, 1)
input_shape2 = (55,)

new = Network_1()

model = new.network_combine1A_1(input_shape1, input_shape2)
model.summary()
```

...why does Python tell me I got this error?

```
   ______________________________________________________________
   TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-40-c02a3146571a> in <module>()
     8     new = Network_1()
     9 
   ---> 10     model = new.network_combine1A_1(input_shape1, input_shape2)
    11     model.summary()

   TypeError: network_combine1A_1() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this error.

Comment: are you using an online interpreter?

Comment: Yes, i used it on the Google Colaboratory. @coder